# Unable to start windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I have upgraded my ubuntu 12.04, with fhe following command.

`sudo apt-get upgrade`
In between some parts were not updated because of some internet issued. So, I had to again run the same command to again start the same upgradation process.

But after that i am unable to start my windows 7. Have no idea why

Instead of window's 7 Its showing `Memtet86+, serial console 115200`. Searched all over the internet applied most solutions from SOLVED answers but still no use.

[Boot info Summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11608525/)

One more strange thing, when I do `grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg` There is no info on windows 7, It provides me following info:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-44-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-44-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-42-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-42-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-41-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-41-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-39-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-39-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-38-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-38-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-29-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-29-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
```

Can anybody provide me the solution for this, as m unable to understand whats going on. Also dont want to corrupt MBR, GRUB etc with various hit n trial. And dont even know that I have already corrupted it. 
Have a very little knowledge of this linux n file systems so dont know whats going on.

**EDIT**

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5fa00889

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   209717247   104755200    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       209717248   347870802    69076777+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       347871230   488396799    70262785    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       347871232   484356095    68242432   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       484358144   488396799     2019328   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: In a terminal window, try running `sudo update-grub`. Hopefully it will find the Windows bootloader, although I wander why it says sda1 and sda2 are unknown file systems. Also, what do you mean by "upgraded"? Aren't you still on 12.04?

Comment: Already tried this no luck.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clarify as to the steps you took to "upgrade 12.04" ? thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek I only upgraded by `sudo apt-get upgrade` took this step because i had missing `GLIBCXX_3.4.18` in libstdc++.so.6 which was required to run mongo db daemon process. Even that problem cudnt solved so I tried upgrading my system, thought that might help upgrade `gcc`

Comment: The steps you took should in no way effect an alternate operating system. I realize that your problem is the reverse but Simply reinstall grub using the accepted answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: @ElderGeek Followed that link, but the command `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` is showing error that `device is write protected mounting read-only`

Comment: As it says:  make sure you use the correct partition number for your system! [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo fdisk -l
` and I'll try to help you locate it.

Comment: @ElderGeek Edited the question. Also included my boot log summary in the link. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your Linux partition is `/dev/sda5` based on your output. follow the answer I previously linked but substitute `/dev/sda5` for /dev/sda2 as it's written in the answer.

Comment: @ElderGeek But why do I need to mount ubuntu ? as Its already booting ...but the problem I have is with windows ?

Comment: @ElderGeek Followed all the steps as suggested still getting `Memtet86+, serial console 115200` instead of windows 7